# Failure Rate calculation based on manufacturing defects (electronics-capacitor)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, exponential-distribution, reliability

Electronics failure rates typically follow the exponential distribution and models like Prism, Mil-Hdbk-217 or 217Plus (newer) are used to predict failure rates.

I'm using 217Plus model for electronics failure rate prediction but this is irrelevant for my question. We are currently in the production phase and fielding our electro-mechanical systems but there seems to be a manufacturing defect within the capacitors by the vendor where much higher failures are being experienced attributed to knit-line defects or delamination at the electrode-dielectric junction, and the failures are occurring during final testing just prior fielding or even after they have been fielded.

My question is, if the capacitor have been modeled using our assumptions (exponential dist, power, vibe and thermal stresses), and manufacturing defects or screening escapes have occurred, then doesn't this mean that our modeled failure rate is NOT relevant anymore? Even calculating a point estimated failure rate (number of failures/accrued number of hours) is pointless (pun, ha) since this particular failure trend is un-modeled and a point estimate only represents a failure rate up until that point in time, and tomorrow we could realize we have many more failures in the field and that failure rate isn't a rate as expected.

How can this new failure rate be calculated/modeled given this manufacturing defect/screening escape? I realize the best thing to do is to chase the root cause and have corrective actions in place but at this point that is difficult as there are many fielded systems already in place.

Comment: If I understand the difficulty with the new model correctly, I do not see that you have any way to predict its failure rate. Perhaps when the capacitor problem is resolved, the failure rate will be similar to that of similar older models.

Comment: I understand what you mean Bruce, but there should be a way to take an educated guess at the new model, given the time between failures perhaps?

Comment: If you have a well-reasoned way to look at data from the current defective process, I suggest you propose that and see what we can make of it. Difficult to muster much useful intuition at a distance how to interpret "much higher failures are being experienced". Can you separate out _capacitor_ failures from _ordinary_ ones?

Comment: The root cause is the capacitor for these particular failures.  What I meant by "much higher failures" is that a certain number like x failures / hours are expected/predicted using the model and the current experience is 50x failures / hour.